# How to catch a result from IActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

Consider having filter with type of `IActionFilter`

```cs
// example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-exceptions-to-modify-the-response

public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order => int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException httpResponseException)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(httpResponseException.Value)
            {
                StatusCode = httpResponseException.StatusCode
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how could i catch this `context.Result` property to use it like a return type?
For example, i have a controller method that should normally return (for example) response 200, but under some exceptions that can be handled inside my filter, the filter itself could return 404. So back to the question, is it possible to catch this `context.Result`? And if so, what is the best practices of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try using [ExceptionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.exceptionfilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

For example:

```
public class UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Customize this object to fit your needs
        var result = new ObjectResult(new
        {
            context.Exception.Message, // Or a different generic message
            context.Exception.Source,
            ExceptionType = context.Exception.GetType().FullName,
        })
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };
        // Set the result
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

And in Program.cs(global):

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute()));
```

Or apply it to a controller or action:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute))]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

At this point in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute>();
```

Hope this can help you.